# Dark Mode is enabled, the menu bar extra icons aren't visible

Tags: macos

I received this error from Apple at the time of publication of my application. how can I solve this problem?

"We found that when Dark Mode is enabled, the menu bar extra icons aren't visible."

I can not find anything online to define Dark mode...

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of something in your app? Check your background colours, as if they are black, they may 'obstruct' or 'hide' your menu bar icons at the top of your screen. (service, carrier, time, battery, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like your app has an icon in the upper right of the menu bar. If that icon has dark colors it's barely visible in Mojave's Dark Mode.

There are several solutions:

- As suggested in the [first item of Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/menu-bar-extras/), you can provide a template image (`myImage.isTemplate = true`). This takes care of drawing it in an appropriate color.
- Provide an image that uses colors that are visible both on a bright and a dark background.
- In Xcode 10, you can add an [image asset with both a light and dark variant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/providing_images_for_different_appearances) (*note:* Xcode 10 **must** run on macOS 10.14 Mojave or later so that dark mode assets are compiled; on earlier macOS versions the app compiles without additional warnings but the dark mode assets are not in the catalog).

Comment: Thanks for your help. in the current version I use these images for the application. how can I proceed? 

https://ibb.co/kmFgNU

Answer (score -2):

Im presuming your app is going onto the mac app store. In MacOS Mojave there is a new feature called dark mode. It basically turns all app UI (Apple Apps) A darker colour instead of white. They must mean that when that mode is enabled your menu bar extra icons arent visable.

Example of dark and light mode:
[image: Light Mode]

[image: Dark Mode]

Comment: Not sure. It might be easier if you had a computer running mojave. Maybe if you have a friend or something or if you install it on your device.